Duality property for supremum and infimum
The problem is found in Abbott’s Understanding Analysis (Exercise 1.3.3.a) and states
Let $A$ be nonempty and bounded below, and define $B = \lbrace b \in \mathbb{R}: b \text{ is a lower bound for } A \rbrace$. Show that sup $B$ = inf $A$.
My attempt at the proof is broken up in the following statements:

$B$ is bounded above.
sup $B$ is a lower bound of $A$.
sup $B$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$.

Proof:

From the definition of $B$, it follow that $b\leq a$ for every $b \in B$ and $a \in A$. Thus, any element of $A$ is an upper bound of $B$.

Using the Axiom of Completeness, we know that sup $B$ exists. Suppose that sup $B$ is not a lower bound of $A$. Then, there must be an element $a \in A$ such that $a < \text{sup } B$ (This is the negation of the definition of lower bound). We fix an element $\alpha$ as having this property ($\alpha < \text{sup B}$). Since $\alpha \in A$, it follows that $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $B$. But this contradicts the fact that sup $B$ is the least upper bound of $B$. Thus, sup $B$ must be a lower bound for $A$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and suppose that $\text{sup } B + \epsilon$ is a lower bound for $A$. That is, $\text{sup }B + \epsilon \leq a$ for every $a \in A$. Then, by definition of $B$, $\text{sup }B + \epsilon \in B$, which is a contradiction since $\text{sup }B + \epsilon > \text{sup }B$. Hence, $\text{sup }B + \epsilon$ is not a lower bound for $A$. This shows that sup $B$ is the greatest lower bound for $A$, that is, $\text{sup } B = \text{inf }A$.


My question is, first of all, if the proof is correct. Also, as I was writing the proof I felt that a proof without contradiction was possible, however I’m not sure. I would appreciate any sketches of a proof that didn’t use any contradiction. Thanks.

First, in order to say the supremum exists you need to verify that $B$ is not empty. In this case this is almost immediate, but still, better not to forget this detail.
And yes, you don't need any proofs by contradiction here. In part $1$ you already showed that any $a\in A$ is an upper bound of $B$. Since the supremum is the least upper bound, it follows that any $a\in A$ satisfies $\sup(B)\leq a$. So that is indeed a lower bound of $A$, and part $2$ follows.
As for part $3$: if $x$ is any lower bound of $A$ then by definition we have $x\in B$, and hence $x\leq\sup(B)$. That's it, this means this is the greatest lower bound. Using $\epsilon$ is really unnecessary.
